# Three-part for loop incrementing value increasing past its limit

Tags: perl, for-loop, increment, nested-loops

I'm writing some code in Perl to test numbers and determine if all their digits are entirely even or entirely odd. I ran the program with `$ARGV[0] = 3` and `$ARGV[1] = 1`. I was having some trouble and added the line to check the values of `$n` each time the outer loop ran through. The values of `$n` were 1, 2 and 2. I was wondering why `$n` was increasing past 1.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my $even = 0;
my $odd = 0;
my $limit = $ARGV[0]; #highest number considered
my $places = $ARGV[1]; #number of places in said number

for($x = 1; $x <= $limit; $x++){

my @z;

my $tot = 0;

my $c = $x;

for($n = 1; $n <= $places; $n++){
    $z[$n] = $c % 2;
    $tot = $tot + $z[$n];
    $c = $c - $z[$n];
    if($c == 0){
        last;
    }
    $c = $c / 10;
}

print $n;

if ($tot == 0) {
    $even++;
}elsif($tot == 1) {
    $odd++;
}

}

print $even . "\n";
print $odd;
```

I haven't coded in Perl before, so sorry if it's a tad inelegant.

Comment: When I change the code as suggested by Kevin I get the error message that `$places` is undefined

Comment: `$0` holds the string of the program running. You had it correct initially and should be using `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having issues with the value of `$n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the value of `$n` after the loop.  The first iteration through the loop `$n` is set to `1`, after the loop `$n` is incremented (`$n++`) and then `$n <= $places` sees that `2 > 1` so the for loop terminates and thus `2` is printed.

Comment: It looks like the logic still needs some work which I can help you with if needed. One additional comment I have is that it is highly recommended to have both `use warnings` and `use strict` at the beginning of your program. Without these it is easy to make simple logic mistakes that Perl will gladly ignore.

Comment: @i5a1ah next time use `for(my $n=0; $n <= $places; $n++)` which will create a locally scoped variable that will not exist outside the loop and won't cause this type of confusion.

Comment: @terdon - Or perhaps `for my $n ( 0 .. $places ) { ...` instead of the C-style loop.

Comment: Ya, C++ was my first language so I tend to use it's style more... Something to be aware of I guess

Answer (score 2):

*I'm writing some code in Perl to test numbers and determine if all their digits are entirely even or entirely odd.*

The following doesn't answer your question, but perhaps it will be helpful, nonetheless:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = 2468;
my $c;

$c += $_ % 2 for split '', $n;

if ( !$c) {
    print "$n has all even digits.\n";
}
elsif ( $c  == length $n ) {
    print "$n has all odd digits.\n";
}
else {
    print "$n has a mixture of even and odd digits.\n";
}
```

The `split ''` splits the number into its digits, and `$c += $_ % 2` is done `for` each one of them.  `Even mod 2` returns `0`, so if `$c` is zero, the number has only even digits.  `Odd mod 2` returns `1`, so if `$c` is the same as the length of the string `$n`, then number has only odd digits.  Otherwise, the number consists of a mixture of even and odd digits.